# A sphere missing a piece is called what? an incomplete sphere?

Tags: terminology

What can we call a sphere that is missing a spherical sector or any other connected  piece ?
  What can we call a sphere minus an open simple curve ?

I have found in page 96 in "Heather A. Dye,An Invitation to Knot Theory: Virtual and Classical, CRC Press, 2016"
that a punctured sphere is formed by selecting a single point on the sphere
and removing all points withing a certain distance, say $\delta$, from that point while keeping points with the exact distance $\delta$ to form a boundary.

Comment: A punctured sphere?

Comment: @Bernard sounds plausible. What about a cracked sphere for the ones missing an open simple curve.

Comment: @bernard A punctured sphere sounds like a sphere missing a single point, not a region of positive length or area.

Comment: @Mark S. I added a remark in the question.

Comment: A crippled sphere :P

Comment: ASMAROPL: "A Sphere Missing A Region Of Positive Length". :P

Comment: Topologically they are all homeomorphic to a closed disk.